# «Рыбка уже в уже»: значение

Tags: лексика, значение-слов, история, старая-орфография

В известном тексте И. А. Ильина о реформе орфографии предлагается добраться до смысла «в следующих речениях»: *рыбка уже в уже; на горе других цветов не было*.

Собственно, вопрос об их смысле.

Comment: Вопрос ставится о смысле того, что курсивом приведено?

Comment: @Alex_ander именно!

Comment: Тогда отвечу как понял :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Собственно, вопрос об их смысле.

Речь у Ильина идёт о том, что при упразднении *ятей* потерялось различие в написаниях слов ***у***же и *(в) уж**е***, *г**о**ре* и *(на) гор**е***.

Написанные им выражения имеют в новой орфографии двоякий смысл.

Comment: Да, это ясно. Спасибо. Я просто искал в этом чего-то более глубокого, потому что примеры показались необычными.

Answer (score 0):

Вероятно, это отчёт о выполнении задания, заключавшегося в том, чтобы выяснить, есть ли на горе другие цветы, кроме известных, и успел ли уж съесть рыбку.

**P. S.** В каждом из выражений при желании можно увидеть двусмысленность: рыбка внутри ужа становится более узкой, а на горе, принадлежащей другим, не было цветов.

Comment: Я примерно о том и подумал, но согласуется ли это с пламенной речью в защиту великой старой орфографии? ) Или это что-то из гимназических "приколов"?

Comment: А где весь текст можно посмотреть?

Comment: http://imwerden.de/pdf/iljin_o_russkom_pravopisanii.pdf. Про ужа на пятой странице..

Comment: Видимо, двусмысленность или трудность понимания уходит при возвращении "яти".

Comment: «...на горе, принадлежащей другим»? Это ж в каком смысле?

Comment: В притяжательном смысле "гора других" (не своя гора); видимо, автор имел в виду третий смысл, "гОре других", хотя падеж в таком варианте плохо подходит (на гОре другИМ убедительнее).